# Sinatra + MongoDB resulting in unRESTful API?

Tags: mongodb, rest, http, nosql

I consume a webservice API that is written in Sinatra and uses a nonrelational database (MongoDB).

There are things stored like this:

```
article:{
    "title:"foo",
    "comments": ["first comment", "lolz", "fake comment"],
    "foo", "bar"
}
```

The update method requires me to send ALL the data AGAIN with the modified values. So, if I want to add a comment   I need to send:

```
article: {
    "title:"foo",
    "comments": ["first comment", "lolz", "fake comment", "another comment"],
    "foo", "bar"
}
```

This may result in data loss. For example:

Bob gets the article on his iPhone. Alice gets the same article on her iPad. They read it. Bob decides to leave a long comment. Alice leaves a short comment and finishes before Bob (makes the update request). Bob finishes after a while and makes his comment - makes the update request rewriting Alice's comment.

I argued that this is a problem. The result of this was a new API call to ADD a comment to an article with a specific ID - not sending again all the existing parameters.

This is still not ok (if I do update a parameter, I still have to send the arrays). I guess that the array fields of a model should not be available when doing POST or PUT.
There should be another resource called URL (at least for the end user if the model in the DB remains the same).

I don't know a good approach on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example - I don't know if you're using Mongoid or what. These are just off the cuff, so apologies if there's something not quite right.

Say you've got an article model with a method like:

```
class Article
    # Stuff
    def add_comment(comment)
        @comments.push comment
    end
    # More stuff.
end
```

I don't see why there can't be a route like:

```
post '/api/article/:article_id/comment/:comment' do
    # retrieve an article by its ID.
    article.add_comment params[:comment]
    article.save
end
```

Even if you didn't have a model, it's just a matter of a query like:

```
article_collection.update(
    {_id: BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:article_id])},
    {"$push" => {comments: {params[:comment]}},
    {w: 1} # Or 0 if you like to live dangerously.
)
```

Comment: i think this is a good approach, so the client don't need to sent the entire row to the server each time, just the server cares to add in the corresponding spot the comment...